# WPF Datagrid, sort on autogenerated column containing IP Address

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

When using the following code, the IP address column is not sortable (nothing happens when you click on the header and the sorting event is not triggered). How can I make the IP Address column sortable?

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace DGrid1
{
    public class Item
    {
        public IPAddress Address { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Collection { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            Collection = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            Collection.Add(new Item {Address=IPAddress.Parse("192.168.201.123"), Name="fred" });
            Collection.Add(new Item { Address = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.201.241"), Name = "jim" });
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private void grid_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Column);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DGrid1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" x:Name="grid" Sorting="grid_Sorting"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to define manually each column inside the XAML of your DataGrid with this syntax:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="grid" Sorting="grid_Sorting">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="IP" Binding="{Binding Address}" SortMemberPath="Address" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" SortMemberPath="Name" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you. That works, but why is sorting disabled for IP addresses when the columns are autogenerated?

Comment: This is not *really* sortable: look at my answer, I'm choosing a sortable property and preserving the original auto-generation

Comment: @AdrianS because .NET doesn't know how to sort your class Item, so when the columns are autogenerated, WPF doesn't know how to generate a sortable column for the Address property. When you manually write the DataGridTextColumn tag, you specify the property Address.